# Merge js files regardless formatting. ex. merging esprima ast's

Tags: javascript, merge, abstract-syntax-tree, esprima

Do you know any tool for merging a js file into an other but keep the formatting?

ex.,
merge

```js
x({a: 5, b: 6});
```

into

```js
x({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
});
```

and the resoult would be

```js
x({
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
});
```

instead of merging conflict

I think a tool which can merge to js ast (the syntax tree that esprima and FF Parser API produces) in the way of refreshing just the values and leave the formatting informations of the existing blocks as it was wouldn't be so complicated but i didn't find one. Do i miss something?

Comment: I could try to use [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast). But you'd have to build the merging logic yourself.

Comment: ^ I meant "You could try..."

Comment: did you find anything or build anything?